# Returning all matches from a series of regex captures

Tags: ruby, regex

I've a string which contains many fields I'd like to extract from it.
These I can easily parse from the line with regex, but I'd like to grab them all at once.

My string is:

```
>sp|P31946-2|1433B_HUMAN Isoform Short of 14-3-3 protein beta/alpha OS=Homo sapiens GN=YWHAB
```

I'd like to use something like this:

```
id, entry, protein, organism, gene, existence, seq_version = (1..6).each do |i|
  line[/^>sp\|(\w*)\|(\w*)\s(.*)\sOS=(.+)\sGN=(.+)\sPE=(\d*)\sSV=(\d*)/, i]
end
```

Mainly, I'd just like to have one line of code to capture all of these attributes from the entry string.  Is there a way to do it?

Comment: One of the primary goals for writing code is to make it readable and maintainable. Trying to make all the logic fit into one line of code runs afoul of those goals so beware, as you program, that you don't try to be clever or macho, and make your code harder to understand in the future when you, or someone else, has to revisit the code for some modifications. A lot of times the code remains much more readable when the logic is spread over several lines.

Comment: It would help a lot if you gave a sample of the expected output/captured text. Your sample regex isn't correct so it won't match.

Comment: I changed the code from a one-liner to a three-liner. Apologies if it makes it less "1337".

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on my first SO question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

also,

```
>> "THX1138".scan(/(.)(.)(\d+)(\d)/)
=> [["H", "X", "113", "8"]]
```

Comment: I like this one for acting on the object according to my paradigm, and for reducing the number of method calls.

Answer (score 3):

[MatchData#captures](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/MatchData.html#M000408)

```
f1,f2,f3,f4 = /(.)(.)(\d+)(\d)/.match("THX1138.").captures
f1    #=> "H"
f2    #=> "X"
f3    #=> "113"
f4    #=> "8"
```